# Rspec undefined method `route_to' when testing one route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to Rspec and am trying to test the one route in my application. I have installed Rspec and have included the routing file in `spec/routing/routes_spec.rb`.

My spec is as follows:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Routes" do
  it "routes get index" do
    expect(:get => "simulations").to route_to(
      :controller => "simulations",
      :action => "index"
    )
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Routes routes get index
    Failure/Error: expect(:get => "simulations").to route_to(
    NoMethodError:
      undefined method `route_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Routes:0x007fc32d2f70b8 @__memoized=nil>
    # ./spec/routing/routes_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas as to why `route_to` would be undefined? I have verified that the route actually works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rspec 3 you should `require 'rails_helper'` rather than `require 'spec_helper'`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs):

> Routing specs are marked by `:type => :routing` or if you have set `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` by placing them in *spec/routing*.

So, unless you set the previous option, you should begin your spec with:

```rb
describe "Routes", :type => :routing do
```

Comment: The Spec still fails when using describe "Routes", :type => :routing do. The file is also placed in spec/routing so it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: It shouldn't be needed if you specify `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` or if you are on rspec 2. On rspec 3, if you don't specify that it is needed. That being said, we need your spec helper. Also, do you `require 'spec_helper'` on top of your spec file? That's very important and might be the cause

Comment: if I place config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location! in spec_helper under the line RSpec.configure do |config|, I get the error undefined method config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location! Also, require 'spec_helper' is the top line of my spec file. I have also verified that my Rspec version is >3.0

Comment: You might need `require 'rails_helper'` (and add the config there) based on your setup (in my case I was using only spec helper). Did you include rspec-rails in your gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

As Fire-Dragon-DoL suggests above, you might like to check that the rspec-rails gem is in place.

When you don't have rspec-rails installed and required, and you use *to_route* method, you will get the same error when running your specs: *NoMethodError: undefined method 'route_to'*

Given the same setup, when you use *be_routable* matcher, then you get another error, in the style of: *expected {:get=>"/my_models/} to respond to 'routable?'*

To remedy these errors

1. Add *rspec-rails* to **Gemfile**
2. Run *bundle install*
3. Add *require 'rspec/rails'* to **spec_helper** (or rails_helper)